# How do I put multiple things in an array in the local storage and pick out the one i need?

Tags: javascript

I am making this announcement program for teachers and students where the teacher puts in values such as grade gender club and the announcement, and a student page that lets you choose the grade gender and club you are in to show the announcements that are there for those values. Now I have a problem. I have created an array which allows for me to put in multiple different announcements but I cant get the array to function and show up in the student page. Here are the 2 different js codes

Teacher page js code

```
var teacherGrade = [];
var teacherGender = [];
var teacherClub = [];
var teacherAnnouncement = [];
var counter = 0;

function getData() {
  //alert("here");
  teacherGrade[counter] = document.getElementById("htmlTGrade").value
  teacherGender[counter] = document.getElementById("htmlTGender").value
  teacherClub[counter] = document.getElementById("htmlTClub").value
  teacherAnnouncement[counter] = document.getElementById("htmlTAnnouncement").value
  localStorage.setItem("teacherGradeKey", JSON.stringify(teacherGrade));
  localStorage.setItem("teacherGenderKey", JSON.stringify(teacherGender));
  localStorage.setItem("teacherClubKey", JSON.stringify(teacherClub));
  localStorage.setItem("teacherAnnouncementKey", JSON.stringify(teacherAnnouncement));
  counter++;
}

function getExsistingAnnouncement() {

  if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teacherGradeKey")) != null) {
    teacheGrade = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teacherGradeKey"));
    teacherGender = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teacherGenderKey"));
    teacherClub = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teacherClubKey"));
    teacherAnnouncement = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teacherAnnouncementKey"));
    counter = teacherGrade.length;
  }
}

//function checkArray() {
//var checkGrade = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teacherGrade"));
//alert("Grade from Local Storage = ", checkGrade);
//var checkGender = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teacherGender"));
//alert("Gender from Local Storage = ", checkGender);
//var checkClub = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teacherClub"));
//alert("Club from Local Storage = ", checkClub);
//var checkAnnouncement = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("teacherAnnouncement"));
//alert("Announcement from Local Storage = ", checkAnnouncement);
//}
```

Student Page js code

```
var teacherGrade = [];
var teacherGender = [];
var teacherClub = [];
var teacherAnnouncement = [];
var studentGrade;
var studentGender;
var studentClub;
var counter = 0;
var annoucnementTextHolder = " ";

function displayAnnouncement() {
  teacherGrade[counter] = localStorage.getItem("teacherGradeKey");
  teacherGender[counter] = localStorage.getItem("teacherGenderKey");
  teacherClub[counter] = localStorage.getItem("teacherClubKey");
  teacherAnnouncement[counter] = localStorage.getItem("teacherAnnouncementKey");
  studentGrade = localStorage.getItem("studentGradeKey");
  studentGender = localStorage.getItem("studentGenderKey");
  studentClub = localStorage.getItem("studentClubKey");
  annoucnementTextHolder += teacherAnnouncement;
  counter++;

  for (var i = 0; i < teacherGrade.length; i++) {
    if ((teacherGrade[i] == studentGrade || teacherGrade[i] == "Select all") && (teacherGender[i] == studentGender || teacherGender[i] == "Select all") && (teacherClub[i] == studentClub || teacherClub[i] == "Select all")) {} else {
      document.getElementById("htmlSViewerText").innerHTML = "Sorry no announcement"
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("htmlSViewerText").innerHTML = annoucnementTextHolder;

}
```

Comment: You do understand that `localStorage` only exists on the single machine, in that one browser, for each person, yes?  It is not shared otherwise.

Comment: You have lots of misspelled words. Some that don't even match the misspelled variable they reference.  I'm looking at `teacheGrade` and `teacherGrade` for example.  Or `annoucnementTextHolder` or `getExsistingAnnouncement`.  Each time I see these, I think maybe the misspellings are inconsistent and that's the problem. But even if they're not, I still don't see an array anywhere that's supposed to be driving this "program." I think you need to provide a minimal example.